# How to install and virtualize Windows 10 from USB stick?

Tags: windows, virtualization

I have a bootable Windows 10 USB that I bought at Best Buy. Is there any way to install and virtualize it on my Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [Parallels Desktop](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/) you can import bootable disks as virtual disks. Choose File → New, select existing disk, then choose USB Drive and follow the instructions.

[image]